# MBCalendarKit: Connecting CKCalendarDataSource to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, mbcalendarkit, ios-library, ios-subclass

I'm connecting [MBCalendarKit](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit/) with Core Data.

This is the code to build a dictionary of events:

```
for (Task *task in _taskArray)
{
    _event = [CKCalendarEvent eventWithTitle:[task valueForKey:@"title"] andDate:[task valueForKey:@"startDate"] andInfo:nil];
    [_eventsArray addObject:_event];
}
 // Moving events to Dictionary
[_calendarData setObject:_eventsArray forKey:_event.date];
```

---

When implementing the method *CKCalendarDataSource* the outcome is not the desired one. I get all the events in the array for every date in the calendar, as shown below.

```
- (NSArray *)calendarView:(CKCalendarView *)calendarView eventsForDate:(NSDate *)date {
   return _calendarData[_event.date];
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *CKCalendarDataSource* is expecting a specific Dictionary format I had to iterate through eventsArray instead of just passing it to _calendarData.

```
{
    "July 15, 2014" =     (
        "<CKCalendarEvent: 0x1123128e0>"
    );
    "July 16, 2014" =     (
        "<CKCalendarEvent: 0x11230fb10>",
        "<CKCalendarEvent: 0x11230ff00>"

    "July 18, 2014" =     (
        "<CKCalendarEvent: 0x11230d880>",
        "<CKCalendarEvent: 0x11230df30>"
    );
}
```

---

```
[eventsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([_calendarData objectForKey:[[eventsArray objectAtIndex:idx]date]]) {
        // Dictionary already contains object with this date

        NSMutableArray *existingDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [existingDate addObjectsFromArray:[_calendarData objectForKey:[[eventsArray objectAtIndex:idx]date]]];
        [existingDate addObject:object];

        [_calendarData setObject:existingDate forKey:[[eventsArray objectAtIndex:idx]date]];
    }

    else {
        NSMutableArray *uniqueDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [uniqueDate addObject:object];
        [_calendarData setObject:uniqueDate forKey:[[eventsArray objectAtIndex:idx]date]];
    }
}];
```